# How do I launch a console program from a gui?

Tags: java, user-interface, console

This is for an assignment created in BlueJ and submitted as a zip file containing the BlueJ package.

In the package are several independent console programs. I am trying to create another "control panel" program - a gui with radio buttons to launch each program.

Here are 2 of the listener classes I have tried:

```
private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == arraySearchButton)
        {
            new ArraySearch();
        }//end if
            else if(e.getSource() == workerDemoButton)
            {
                new WorkerDemo();
            }//end else if
    }//end actionPerformed
}//end class RadioButtonListener

private class RunButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(arraySearchButton.isSelected())
        {
            new ArraySearch();
        }//end if
            else if(workerDemoButton.isSelected())
            {
                new WorkerDemo();
            }//end else if
    }//end actionPerformed
}//end class RunButtonListener
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's the problem/question? E.g. what happens (or doesn't happen)? How do you know it should be invoked? What is in WorkerDemo?

Comment: @pst
The problem is that the console window never launches. Technically the homework is complete, this is extra.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to launch .EXE console applications, here's some code that could help you. See below for explanation.

```
import java.io.*;


public class Main {

       public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
                Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\helloworld.exe");

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                String line=null;

                while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

First you need an handle on current running java application and to do so you create an Runtime Object and use Runtime.getRuntime(). You can then declare a new process and use the exec call to execute the proper application.

The bufferReader will help print the output of the generated process and print it in the java console.

Finally, pr.waitFor() will force the current thread to wait for the process pr to terminate before going further. exitVal contains the error code if any (0 means no error).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive code, very informative. The console applications, however, are actually other classes in the same BlueJ package as the control panel

Comment: Then why can't you simply create an instance of that class and call the proper functions?

Comment: I thought that's what the above code did; did I miss something?

Comment: The above code lets you create a new process specifying the path to an executable file (.exe). If you have multiple classes in your package you can simply instantiate (aka create an object) of that class and then use it in your control panel. I don't know what's your level of expertise in Java and I'm unsure right now what you are trying to do. Perhaps edit your original post with some more details. Perhaps even a screenshot of your project and more details on what you are really trying to achieve would help.

Comment: Sorry, by "above code" I meant the code that I posted as part of the question. I am using new Classname(); in the action listeners, is that not enough?

Comment: Ok here are a few options. You can make ArraySearch a static class and call the functions when a button (or whatever) is selected. This is the equivalent of a namespace in C++ or as I like to call them utility classes.
If you want to stick to your method, either declare a ArraySearch object in your class or if you want to instantiate the object when you click a button use ArraySearch myArraySearch = new ArraySearch() instead of just new ArraySearch(). Then maybe something like myArraySearch.setVisible(true) if it's another JFrame.